# Fill Entire Cell With Two Components Using MigLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, miglayout

I have two components which I would like to both fill the same cell in a [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/):

For example, I want to give both components constraints something like this:

```
cell 0 0 1 1, push, grow
```

and have them both be placed exactly over top of one another inside `cell 0 0`

(If I just use the code above, they end up sharing space side-by-side in the cell)

What do I have to add to the [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) constraints to make this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up solving the issue by giving the first component an *id* in MigLayout:

`cell 0 0 1 1, push, grow, id myid`

Then explicitly positioned the second component on top of the first using the first component's bounds (referenced using the id):

`pos myid.x myid.y myid.x2 myid.y2`

Comment: lifesaver! I wonder thought if this is the best/recommended way to achieve this! There aren't a lot of examples out there!

Answer (score 0):

Place them in a panel with CardLayout and swap when necessary.

Comment: The components are transparent and I need both showing at once. I figured out how to do it though (see my answer).